# How do I install a RubyGem from NetBeans that I created?

Tags: ruby, netbeans, rubygems

Is it possible to install a RubyGem that I created in NetBeans, through NetBeans without uploading it to RubyForge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is currently no way to do this. Just have to do the normal way and install your gem from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10):

> `gem install` will install the named
>   gem. It will attempt a local
>   installation (i.e. a .gem file in the
>   current directory), and if that fails,
>   it will attempt to download and
>   install the most recent version of the
>   gem you want.

So, you should be able to just run gem from the directory with your .gem file.

Comment: I was hoping to do it right from netbeans. So that I don't have to leave the IDE each time I 'rake gem' to install it.